# Align <a> element bottom inside ionic column

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to align `<a>` tag element bottom of the column, I tried putting margin, padding on top/bottom but not making any impact,The image attached is the current status , I want the 'link' to go down and sit in same level button base, is there any recommended way to achieve this.

```
      <ion-row style="display: flex;">
              <ion-col text-right>
                <a href="" class="headerLink">Report
                  a Problem</a>
                <button color="light" ion-button  (click)="writebackData()">Button1</button>
                <button color="light" ion-button  (click)="writebackData()">Button2</button>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            .headerLink{
          color: red;
          padding-right: 3px;

align-items: center;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: `align-items: center` if you are using flexbox in the `ion-row`

Comment: It made no difference,  'link' to go down and sit in same level of button base

Comment: I'll ask, are you using `display: flex` on the `ion-row`?

Comment: No , I am not using that

Comment: Then of course it won't work; that's why I said *"if you are using flexbox"*, try adding it and see if it changes something

Comment: It didn't make any changes, I updated the tag and style above  as I tried

Comment: Well... delete the margin of the `a` tag

Comment: the button  have same height as the link ?

Comment: i was doing it with line-height  but the button will have same height as the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: flex-end;"` in `ion-col` tag will resolve your issue. Thanks

```css
.headerLink{
   color: red;
   padding-right: 3px;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ion-row style="display: flex;">
   <ion-col text-right style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: flex-end;">
      <a href="" class="headerLink">Report a Problem</a>
      <button color="light" ion-button (click)="writebackData()">Button1</button>
      <button color="light" ion-button  (click)="writebackData()">Button2</button>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also had a lot of difficulty aligning items inside the ion-grid. I would suggest making a new ion-row and placing the link inside that.

Answer (score 0):

set the icon-col to inline flex now you can controle it with margin

```css
 .headerLink{
          color: red;
          padding-right: 3px;
          margin-top: 7px;

        }
        ion-col {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
 <ion-row>
              <ion-col text-right>
                <a href="" class="headerLink">Report
                  a Problem</a>
                <button color="light" ion-button  (click)="writebackData()">Button1</button>
                <button color="light" ion-button  (click)="writebackData()">Button2</button>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
```